# Undefined reference to `__time32` ncurses

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, codeblocks, ncurses

**background:** i'm learning how to use ncurses for along the path of implementing a simple roguelike game.

to start off ive been shamelessly copying code from tutorial websites in order to get the IDE set up correctly but in all examples i have run into the same error:

**lib\libncursesw.a(lib_twait.o):lib_twait.c|| undefined reference to `` `__time32 ``'**

the other errors are also in libncursesw.a (twait.c and iterator.c)

**what ive tried:** the -lncurses,-llibcurses --lcurses switches on the linker (MinGW with gcc) to no avail (errors say they can't find -lxxxx)

i have the libncursesw.a included in the libs (within code::blocks)

if you're wondering what the code is that im using (or if it would help in anyway) here it is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
initscr();          /* Start curses mode */
printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World*/
refresh();          /* Print it on to the real screen */
getch();            /* Wait for user input */
endwin();           /* End curses mode */

return 0;
}
```

any help would be muchly appreciated - these sorts of things are always the only obstacle that i cant cross...

**EDIT**

these are the compiler invocations:

for main.o:

`mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -O2     -IC:\Users\User\CBProjects\rogue\include -c C:\Users\User\CBProjects\rogue\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o`

for the executable:

`mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\rogue.exe $(OBJS_RELEASE)  -s  lib\libncursesw.a lib\libncursesw.a`

Comment: Please post your actual compiler invocation.

Comment: I've gone and taken the invocations out of the generated makefile - for better visibility they'll be in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use **gcc** instead of **g++** to produce the exe file.

__time32 is a Windows system function. Ming normally finds the necessary libraries, but sometimes the exact link command is important. See http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/12692/4948/ for a similar situation.

Comment: I solved this issue by recompiling the ncurses library, cheers Alex for the assistance